# How to cut the content in laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to cut the characters that show description with the same quantity of letter in all foreach.

Could anyone helps me?

```
@foreach ($subastas as $subasta)
    @if(($subasta->data_inici <= $data)&&($subasta->data_final>$data))
        <a href="item/{{$subasta->id}}"><div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <div class="single-products">
                    <div class="productinfo text-center">
                        <div class="nombre">{{$subasta->nombre}}</div>
                        @foreach ($subasta->images as $word => $meaning)
                            @if($word==0)
                                <img src="{{ asset($meaning->ruta) }}" style="width="242px" height="164px""/>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                        <h2><span class="clock" data-countdown="{{ $subasta->data_final}}"></span></h2>
                        <p>{{$subasta->descripcion}}</p>
                        <p>{{$subasta->cant_actual}}</p>
                        <a class="pujar btn btn-warning" id="{{$subasta->id}}">Pujar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I think and image is better than explain .
[image]

Comment: You mean to deal with style ?

Comment: I need to cut because the description is more longer than another , and I am interested to show the same characters.

Comment: If you need limit the string then simply `substr` But will it be meaningful if you limit it hardly ?? I guess you need to do alignment in css. Do you need to do it ?

Comment: If you are only concerned about the alignment, then you can just make the description as left aligned (I guess simply limiting the character doesn't makes a sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to limit the number of characters in a string?

This can be done in laravel by a [string helper](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-limit):

```
$value = str_limit('The PHP framework for web artisans.', 7);
```

So in your example:

```
<p>{{ str_limit($subasta->descripcion, 20) }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When whoever inputs the description of the product, can you not use `max-length` within the HTML element to set the limit prior to being saved?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="250" />
```

Comment: Hello @Ben I need this because the description is more longer and I need to cut the description somehow.

Comment: My point being, is that you must have to input the description from somewhere, so why not limit it before you save it?

Comment: Because I use the same row in another page that I need to show all description.

Comment: Right I see, it wasn't clear in your initial question that's all. It appears to have been answered anyways by @Bjorn!